# Is a public getter and a private setter with same name possible in C#?

Tags: c#, properties

How can I create a public getter and a private setter for a property? Is the following correct?

```
public String Password
{
    set { this._password = value; }
}

private String Password
{
    get { return this._password; }
}
```

Comment: your text asks for public String Password {get; private set} but your code is for public String Password { set; private get;} one of those is obviously wrong.

Comment: @Yaur: Good catch, I didn't notice that. But either one will work using the same syntax.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Yes it is possible, even with auto properties. I often use:

```
public int MyProperty { get; private set; }
```

Comment: can you explain what this guy is saying about your answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073392/how-often-do-you-see-abuse-of-c-sharp-shorthand-getters-setters 
is he saying that this is not alright to do? im confused

Comment: That question and Jon's answer says that there are cases where this is not okay, specifically if the value should be readonly (not possible to set after ctor has run) it is wrong to use an auto property. As with any language feature there are both correct and incorrect uses.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, as of C# 2.0, you can specify different access levels for the getter and the setter of a property.

But you have the syntax wrong: you should declare them as part of the same property. Just mark the one you want to restrict with `private`. For example:

```
public String Password
{
    private get { return this._password; }
    set { this._password = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
public String Password
{
    private set { this._password = value; }
    get { return this._password; }
}
```

or you can use an auto-implemented property:

```
public String Password { get; private set; }
```

Comment: this will make both public right? I want to make the getter method only available to class itself, mean private.

Comment: The first bit of code is not correct. It doesn't do what is requested.  The second bit does work.

Comment: I like to place the getter *before* the setter, as is customary with properties having identical access levels.

Answer (score 2):

```
public String Password
{
    private set { this._password = value; }
    get { return this._password; }
}
```

[MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65zdfbdt%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

> The get and set methods are generally
>   no different from other methods. They
>   can perform any program logic, throw
>   exceptions, be overridden, and be
>   declared with any modifiers allowed by
>   the programming language.

Edit:
MSDN quote is just to clarify why geter and setter can have different access mdofiers, Good point raised by @Cody Gray:

> Yes, properties can perform program
>   logic and throw exceptions. But they
>   shouldn't. Properties are intended to
>   be very lightweight methods,
>   comparable to accessing a field. The
>   programmer should expect to be able to
>   use them as they would a field without
>   any noticeable performance
>   implications. So too much heavy
>   program logic is strongly discouraged.
>   And while setters can throw exceptions
>   if necessary, getters should almost
>   never throw exceptions

Comment: Not really if you think about it - they are no different from other functions.

Comment: Yes, properties *can* perform program logic and throw exceptions. But they *shouldn't*. Properties are intended to be very lightweight methods, comparable to accessing a field. The programmer should expect to be able to use them as they would a field without any noticeable performance implications. So too much heavy program logic is strongly discouraged. And while setters can throw exceptions if necessary, getters should almost *never* throw exceptions.

Comment: +1 @Cody Gray - in general I agree, was just quoting what msdn says about it.

Comment: Fair enough. The only point of that statement is to describe their implementation. They are implemented as two separate methods under the hood. It's not giving design recommendations, that's found elsewhere on Microsoft's site. But most people never bother to look at those, evidenced by lots of the code I see posted here. Just because you can do something doesn't mean you should.

Answer (score 2):

```cs
public string Password { get; private set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

To gain an 'Excavator' badge, and to make the answer up to date - readonly fields encapsulated by a get-only property

```
private readonly int myVal;
public int MyVal get { return myVal; }
```

may be now (as of C# 6.0) shortened to

```
public int MyVal { get; }
```