# In ASPNetCore 2.2, Startup.cs, the Configure property only has {get}, yet it is assigned a reference. Why is this?

Tags: asp.net-core

ASPNetCore 2.2:

In Startup.cs, the Configure property only has {get}, yet it is assigned a reference.

I tried this in a normal .net framework app console, (a very simple "class1" object), and this was not permitted.

```
public class Startup
    {
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;  // Configuration is readonly?
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

... etc
```

Comment: It is a readonly auto-property. It's assigned from the constructor so it is allowed.

Comment: Ok thanks. I see there is a duplicate. As soon as I did a search for readonly auto-property, I saw similar questions ...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34743533/automated-property-with-getter-only-can-be-set-why/34743656