# Consolidation of two properties into one property .NET

Tags: c#

I have 2 characteristics
And I want to unite them into one characteristic
I would be happy to help with this

```
public string L_NAME { get; set; }
public string F_NAME { get; set; }
```

Comment: what does "unite them into one characteristic" mean exactly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34934041/3917754 check this

Answer (score 2):

```
public string L_NAME { get; set; }
public string F_NAME { get; set; }
public string Full_Name { get { return F_NAME +" "+ L_NAME; } }
```

> You can use FullName in place of both properties

Comment: You might want to be putting a space between those names...

Comment: @MatthewWatson <= StackOverflow disagrees ;)