# Instance { get; } = new <class>() - Is this a C#7/8/9 feature?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I saw this expression as a short and thread safe to implement a singleton design pattern:

```
public static MySimpleSingleton Instance { get; } = new MySimpleSingleton();
```

What is the meaning of this part in the expression ? Is it kind of coalesce ? What is the formal name of it ?

```
Instance { get; } = new MySimpleSingleton()
```

Comment: That's an [auto-implemented property initialiser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties), which was introduced in C#6.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to give a C# auto-property an initial value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730/what-is-the-best-way-to-give-a-c-sharp-auto-property-an-initial-value), [Automated property with getter only, can be set, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34743533/8967612)

Comment: Note that C# 9 allows you to shorten this even further with the use of target-typed `new`, allowing just `MySimpleSingleton Instance { get; } = new()`.